# Joining three pieces of Code "Open Dialog Box" "Cut and Paste" and "Split Column Rename"

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

I hope you can help. I have below three pieces of code. All three work perfectly independent of one another. Everything compiles the Macro just wont execute correctly.

The first piece of code `Sub Open_Workbook_Dialog()` opens a dialog box and allows a user to select a file.

The second piece of code `Public Sub Sample()` searches column headings for the text 'CountryCode' then cuts that column and pastes it into column F.

The third piece of code `Public Sub Filter()`  takes column F and splits it into new worksheets and renames the worksheet based on the country.

So essentially what the macro is supposed to do is open a dialog box get the file, find the country column where ever it is, cut it and paste it into column F then split this column into new sheets and rename.

Like i said all the code works fine independently but when i put them together. The dialog box opens I select my file then I get the Msgbox **"Country not Found"** even though the CountryCode Column is well in range *I think* `Set aCell = .Range("A1:X50")`CountryCode is in Column W.

Once i click the MsgBox **"Country not Found"** the `Public Sub Filter()` executes and splits and renames the wrong column. The find does not seem to be happening, hence the cut and paste is not happening.

I have attached pics for better understanding.

Country Not found

[image: Country not Found]

Split by the wrong F 
[image]

CODE BELOW

```
Sub Open_Workbook_Dialog()

Dim my_FileName As Variant

    MsgBox "Pick your TOV file" '<--| txt box for prompt to pick a file

        my_FileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files,*.xl*;*.xm*") '<--| Opens the file window to allow selection

    If my_FileName <> False Then
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=my_FileName

Call Sample '<--|Calls the Filter Code and executes

Call Filter '<--|Calls the Filter Code and executes

End If


End Sub
Public Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim aCell As Range, Rng As Range
    Dim col As Long, lRow As Long
    Dim colName As String

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        Set aCell = .Range("A1:X50").Find(What:="CountryCode", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    '~~> If Found
    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then

    '~~> Cut the entire column
    aCell.EntireColumn.Cut

    '~~> Insert the column here
    Columns("F:F").Insert Shift:=xlToRight

    Else
    MsgBox "Country Not Found"

    End If
    End With
End Sub
Public Sub Filter()
    Dim rCountry As Range, helpCol As Range

    With Worksheets("Sheet1") '<--| refer to data worksheet
        With .UsedRange
            Set helpCol = .Resize(1, 1).Offset(, .Columns.Count) '<--| get a "helper" column just at the right of used range, it'll be used to store unique country names in
        End With

        With .Range("A1:Q" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row) '<--| refer to its columns "A:Q" from row 1 to last non empty row of column "A"
            .Columns(6).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=helpCol, Unique:=True '<-- call AdvancedFilter on 6th column of the referenced range and store its unique values in "helper" column
            Set helpCol = Range(helpCol.Offset(1), helpCol.End(xlDown)) '<--| set range with unique names in (skip header row)
            For Each rCountry In helpCol '<--| iterate over unique country names range (skip header row)
                .AutoFilter 6, rCountry.Value2 '<--| filter data on country field (6th column) with current unique country name
                If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells.Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then '<--| if any cell other than header ones has been filtered...
                    Worksheets.Add Worksheets(Worksheets.Count) '<--... add new sheet
                    ActiveSheet.Name = rCountry.Value2  '<--... rename it
                    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy ActiveSheet.Range("A1") 'copy data for country under header
                End If
            Next
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False '<--| remove autofilter and show all rows back
    End With
    helpCol.Offset(-1).End(xlDown).Clear '<--| clear helper column (header included)
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean 'when I put them together'? Are you calling them one at a time from another `Sub`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are not searching for the "CountryCode" in the opened workbook, but in the workbook you are running your code from. So basically you have a workbook where you start your macro code and open another workbook you want to work with (by using your dialog). But in your `Public Sub Sample()` your problem is the line:

```
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
```

The problem is that you are referencing the workbook, where your macro code is written and executed in by using `ThisWorkbook`. Since you don't know the filename in your `Public Sub Sample()`. I have edited your code to work the way it should:

```
Sub Open_Workbook_Dialog()

Dim my_FileName As Variant
Dim my_Workbook As Workbook

  MsgBox "Pick your TOV file" '<--| txt box for prompt to pick a file

  my_FileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files,*.xl*;*.xm*") '<--| Opens the file window to allow selection

  If my_FileName <> False Then
    Set my_Workbook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=my_FileName)

    Call Sample(my_Workbook)'<--|Calls the Filter Code and executes

    Call Filter(my_Workbook) '<--|Calls the Filter Code and executes

  End If
End Sub

Public Sub Sample(my_Workbook as Workbook)
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim aCell As Range, Rng As Range
  Dim col As Long, lRow As Long
  Dim colName As String

  '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
  Set ws = my_Workbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

  With ws
    Set aCell = .Range("A1:X50").Find(What:="CountryCode", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    '~~> If Found
    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
      '~~> Cut the entire column

      aCell.EntireColumn.Cut

      '~~> Insert the column here

      Columns("F:F").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Else
      MsgBox "Country Not Found"
    End If
  End With
End Sub

Public Sub Filter(my_Workbook as Workbook)
  Dim rCountry As Range, helpCol As Range

  With my_Workbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") '<--| refer to data worksheet
    With .UsedRange
      Set helpCol = .Resize(1, 1).Offset(, .Columns.Count) '<--| get a "helper" column just at the right of used range, it'll be used to store unique country names in
    End With

    With .Range("A1:Q" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row) '<--| refer to its columns "A:Q" from row 1 to last non empty row of column "A"
      .Columns(6).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=helpCol, Unique:=True '<-- call AdvancedFilter on 6th column of the referenced range and store its unique values in "helper" column
      Set helpCol = Range(helpCol.Offset(1), helpCol.End(xlDown)) '<--| set range with unique names in (skip header row)
      For Each rCountry In helpCol '<--| iterate over unique country names range (skip header row)
        .AutoFilter 6, rCountry.Value2 '<--| filter data on country field (6th column) with current unique country name
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells.Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then '<--| if any cell other than header ones has been filtered...
          Worksheets.Add Worksheets(Worksheets.Count) '<--... add new sheet
          ActiveSheet.Name = rCountry.Value2  '<--... rename it
          .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy ActiveSheet.Range("A1") 'copy data for country under header
        End If
      Next
    End With
    .AutoFilterMode = False '<--| remove autofilter and show all rows back
  End With
  helpCol.Offset(-1).End(xlDown).Clear '<--| clear helper column (header included)
End Sub
```

You might also want to change the lines with `.Sheets("Sheet1")` (or `.Worksheets("Sheet1")`) into `.Sheets(1)` (or `.Worksheets(1)`) so you don't rely on the naming in the opened workbook.

Comment: Truly Truly awesome work here mate. Much respect from Dublin you made my Friday. :-) Have a great weekend.

Answer (score 1):

Include column which has CountryCodes (column W in this case) in your line while setting aCell variable.

Comment: Just a reminder, X is after W in the alphabet, so it's already included! ;)

Comment: Sorry... my bad... please change workbook object while setting worksheet object.

Comment: in Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")  ...........instead of ThisWorkbook mention name of opened workbook.

Answer (score 0):

It's most probably a reference issue.

In plain English, this means that you are not passing the reference of the newly opened workbook and hence your other `Subs` have no clue of which one you are talking about!

I've made an example to show you where to make changes :

```
Sub Open_Workbook_Dialog()
Dim my_FileName As Variant

'~~> Changes here
Dim MainWbk As Workbook
Dim OpenedWbk As Workbook
'~~> Changes here
Set MainWbk = ThisWorkbook

MsgBox "Pick your TOV file"
my_FileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files,*.xl*;*.xm*")

If my_FileName <> False Then
    '~~> Changes here
    Set OpenedWbk = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=my_FileName)
    '~~> Changes here
    Call Sample(OpenedWbk, MainWbk)
    ''~~> Same changes to do here
    'Call Filter
End If


End Sub

'~~> Changes here (arguments to pass the references of the workbooks)
Public Sub Sample(OpenedWbk As Workbook, MainWbk As Workbook)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim aCell As Range, Rng As Range
    Dim col As Long, lRow As Long
    Dim colName As String

    '~~> Changes here
    Set ws = OpenedWbk.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        Set aCell = .Range("A1:X50").Find(What:="CountryCode", _
                    LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            aCell.EntireColumn.Cut
            '~~> Changes here
            MainWbk.Columns("F:F").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        Else
            MsgBox "Country Not Found"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```